# How to call a function inside a button click

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function/block of code written under Sub.

Now I have created a button (in the same excel) and by clicking that I want to execute the function/block of code under Sub.

Currently I am getting a error that Sub or function not defined.

```
Sub Button3_Click()
Call testing
End Sub


Sub testing()

Dim ell As Object
Dim post As String
Dim Count As Double
Dim cm As String

   ------
End Sub

Sub or Function not defined
```

Comment: Where have you created the `testing` procedure? In a normal module, class module, behind a sheet, in `ThisWorkbook`, behind a form? And then where's your `button_click` procedure?

Comment: The testing procedure is in sheet and the button_click is a module

Answer (score 0):

Either you must move your procedure `testing` into a module scope and declare it as `Public` to make it available for other modules, or you need to call it by specifying the sheet scope it is in.

Example if `testing` is in the scope of `Sheet1` then call it from a module like:

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    Sheet1.testing 'you don't need Call
End Sub
```

*Be aware that there are 2 different naming systems for sheets. The VBA-Code-Name of the sheet (this is the one we use here). And the tab name (that can be changed by any user, and that we cannot use here)! Both names may be completely different and are **not** linked to each other.*